# SSL error with BottlePy and GEVENT

Tags: python, azure, ssl, gevent

I need an web-server, in Python, that is as fast as possible.
I found BottlePy, and I changed the default server to Gevent, to be more faster.
But now, when I try send an image to Azure Blobs, I receive this error:

> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'

[image]

Anyone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gevent bug:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gevent/ssl/gevent/olkwX4jUUlU/_OJECy1ppYIJ

fix it installing last one version ( gevent-1.1rc5 )

```
sudo pip install --pre gevent --upgrade
```

The last one is Release Candidate, then you need `--pre` argument.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gevent/5mXt5w2kukE

Comment: Yes, it's a bug for `gevent`, also see https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477.